# Something went wrong: Could not create an Object Storage instance

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'm trying to associate an Object Storage instance with my Spark instance, and I keep getting the error shown here:

[image]

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: This is something specific to bluemix. I'm not sure that you'll get an answer here.

Comment: For this issue, please open a ticket with Bluemix Support. See: http://ibm.biz/Bd49J2. The team will need to look at your environment and obtain more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away on its own - I think it must have been a temporary issue in the Bluemix backend.